# Error in Django Template Blocks

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I don't know why this template syntax produce this kind of error :

```
Invalid block tag: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
```

Here's my code

```
{% if state == 'search' %}
    {% if movement %}
        {% for hidden in raw_rows %)
            <div>{{ hidden.id }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo at the end of the following line (need `}` instead of `)`):

```
{% for hidden in raw_rows %)
                           ^ HERE
```

Fixed version:

```
{% for hidden in raw_rows %}
```